# GoogleBot doing POST requests

Tags: googlebot

Why has GoogleBot started last Friday to do POST-requests on a page. I can see in the logfile (just an example, had about 10.000 entries over the weekend - the url in the log is changed):

```
66.249.79.55 - - [15/Jul/2019:08:34:53 +0000] "POST /Contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16730 "https://www.example.com/Contact/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.79.55 - - [15/Jul/2019:08:35:06 +0000] "POST /Contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16730 "https://www.example.com/Contact/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.79.55 - - [15/Jul/2019:08:35:18 +0000] "POST /Contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16730 "https://www.example.com/Contact/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.79.55 - - [15/Jul/2019:08:35:20 +0000] "POST /Contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16730 "https://www.example.com/Contact/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.79.55 - - [15/Jul/2019:08:35:34 +0000] "POST /Contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16731 "https://www.example.com/Contact/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.79.55 - - [15/Jul/2019:08:35:45 +0000] "POST /Contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16730 "https://www.example.com/Contact/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.79.55 - - [15/Jul/2019:08:35:46 +0000] "POST /Contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16730 "https://www.example.com/Contact/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.79.55 - - [15/Jul/2019:08:36:00 +0000] "POST /Contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16730 "https://www.example.com/Contact/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.79.55 - - [15/Jul/2019:08:36:10 +0000] "POST /Contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16730 "https://www.example.com/Contact/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

Would setting the page to index/nofollow help in stopping this behaviour?

Funny side node: that page is using Google recaptcha V3, so in the google recaptcha stats I can see about 95% of bad requests (looks like they are from Googlebot itself).

Comment: Tried the index/nofollow approach wich doesn't help. Using the robots.txt to disallow the page does help - but it would be preferrable to have it in the search results. Is there any other way to achive this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, GoogleBot is capable and does send POST requests (if it is safe - according to Google) - details [here](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/11/get-post-and-safely-surfacing-more-of.html).

In the same article, it talks about blocking the URL via robots.txt - which is a fair approach, given your contact URL isn't in any way a secret and therefore safe to reference in robots.txt (and block that way). Couldn't confirm whether or not a no-follow will prevent the post request - from my experience "no-follow" is a recommendation rather than a policy.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a lot of Googlebot's POST requests in my nginx access log. With a ratio of 10:1 to GET requests. Those POST requests are not necessary for indexing. They have shorter URL than GET requests:

```
POST /Contact/
GET  /Contact/lang/en/details.html
```

I have prohibited bots from sending POST requests using the following directive in `robots.txt`:

```
Disallow: /Contact/$
```